# Ranger: difficulties passing strings to `open_console`

Tags: ranger

I am starting to use `ranger` on linux,
and I want to bind a key `\` to place the string `scout -ft` in the ranger console.

I added in `rc.conf` the following:
`map open_console scout -ft`

this *does* open the console, but gives a strange string: `-ftscout`

I tried fixing this, but failed.

(I think that a `-0` in `open_console` specifies the location of the string)

Any advise?